# Call function(and pass var) in other running module that changes the vars there

Tags: python, function, import, subprocess, python-module

As a beginner it is hard to formulate the question in one line. But the problem is: I have two modules running next to each other (with subprocess.Popen). I want to pass a var from module1 to a function in module2. That function changes a set of global vars only in module2. Importing does not seem to work because of both modules are running in their own mainloop. (which seems to block the import process.)
Any hints.
Thanks, Peter

Module1.py

```
x=0
y=0

def changePar(v):
    global x, y
    x += v
    y += v

While True:
    #do something
    print(x,y) #hopefully the changed values
```

Module2.py

```
From Module1 import changePar
m1 = 5

Module1.changePar(m1)
    
While True:
    #do something
```

Comment: Which process does the _subprocess.Popen_?

Comment: The two modules are both opened bij subprocess.Popen in a third module.

Comment: when Module2 imports from Module1, it triggers the infinite loop there, and so the import never ends. That is what `if __name__ == '__main__'` is for, to allow imports of modules without starting running scripts accidentally. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: @Plem – 
The _third module_ can hand over the value from _Module2.py_ to _Module1.py_ via the open pipes.

Comment: The __name__ and __main__ situation is solved. But now in module 1 I have two different values of x and y.  In the changePar the new values appear, while in the while-loop the original assigned values stay alive? No clue.... @Armali: how could I do that, to let the third module use the "pipes"?

Answer (score 0):

> how could I do that, to let the third module use the "pipes"?

third module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
M1 = Popen(['python3', 'Module1.py'], stdin =PIPE)
M2 = Popen(['python3', 'Module2.py'], stdout=PIPE)
M1.stdin.write(M2.stdout.readline())
M1.stdin.flush()
```

Module1.py:

```
import os, sys
x=0
y=0

def changePar(v):
    global x, y
    x += v
    y += v

os.set_blocking(sys.stdin.fileno(), False)
while True:
    #do something
    l = sys.stdin.readline()
    if l: changePar(int(l))
    print(x, y) # hopefully the changed values
```

Module2.py:

```
m1 = 5
print(m1, flush=True)
```

Comment: Hai Armali. Thanks for this example. I get an error that stdin is not known. But when there will be more time I will try to dive in deeper.

Comment: That's surprising - for which line do you get this error?

Comment: Sorry. After exact reconstruction of your lines it works. But the last step I need is to send from module2 not only 1 value, but a new value every time something changes somewhere. Now, when I fi. Make a while loop that counts up a value and send that everytime, only the first value gets send. So, where do I go wrong. (I=0 while true: m1=i print(m1, flush =True)

Comment: In order to repeat the procedure, we must also repeat the handover in the third module (last two lines in first code block).

Comment: you mean the M1.stdin... lines? Put them in a while True loop?

Comment: Yes, for example.

Comment: Thanks. All working now. The hickup was that you cannot use a standard print in an PIPE environment because it breaks the pipe.

Comment: You are welcome, though I don't get what you mean by _a standard print_.

Comment: Isn’t it so that the print() sends its info into the pipe and not to the console? (For debug reasons I tried putting a print message in, but the output never reached the console…

Comment: That depends - for Module2 it is as you say, due to the `M2 = Popen(['python3', 'Module2.py'], stdout=PIPE)`; for the other modules, it isn't so. In case of `stdout=PIPE`, you could print console messages to `file=sys.stderr`.